# Get the object name of a specific object from namedtuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have recently discovered `namedtuple` and want to use it to replace my icky large class definitions but I am curious if there is a smart way to retrieve the object's name of the value that I just selected, see the below example if it's unclear;

```
MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct","Var1 Var2 Var3")
Instance = MyStruct(1,2,3)
# What I currently do (but hopefully there is a smarter way to do this)
print "Var1:\t"+str(Instance.Var1)+"Var2:\t"+str(Instance.Var2) #and so forth
```

I know that there is the `_fields` option that would look something like this:

```
for x in Instance._fields:
  if str(x) == "Var1" or ... : # I only want to show certain objects at this time
    print x, getattr(Instance,x)
```

Still it looks rather un-pythonic to me, so is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `MyStruct` is a class, not an instance here.

Comment: touche, gave a bad example, corrected it now.

Comment: But what is the real use-case here? Do you have a number of *different* `namedtuple`-derived classes that all have specific fields among other fields and you only wanted to print those specific fields and no others? If so, you may want to rethink your architecture.

Comment: The idea is to create several instances from which I want to select specific attributes at specific time points (and modify them if needed).

Comment: 'same objects' or 'same attributes'? Then you know the fields beforehand, as well as their order in the tuple. Why the extra pain to handle these dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `namedtuple` instance has a [`namedtuple._asdict()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) that returns an ordered dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "Var1 Var2 Var3")
>>> value = MyStruct('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
>>> value._asdict()
OrderedDict([('Var1', 'foo'), ('Var2', 'bar'), ('Var3', 'baz')])
```

This gives you an ordered dictionary with keys and values corresponding to the contents.

However, it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve; what exactly is wrong with just selecting the right field directly?

```
print 'Var1: {}'.format(value.Var1)
```

or picking out specific fields with `str.format()`:

```
print 'Var1: {0.Var1}, Var3: {0.Var3}'.format(value)
```

Comment: I was hoping to not have to resort such print statements but that there would be some magic that allowed something like `print instance.Var1.value, instance.Var1.name` (just to demonstrate the 'idea').

Comment: @BasJansen: But then you are **already** specifying a hard-coded name! Why not use `print "Var1", instance.Var1` in that case?

Comment: I have always wondered about this Martijn, any reason why `_asdict` has underscore?

Comment: @wim: To not needlessly limit the names you can use for your attributes. What if I wanted to have a field `asdict` in my named tuple?

Comment: @BasJansen Just use `instance._asdict().items()[0]` (since its an OrderedDict)

Comment: Strange.  Is that documented somewhere?  Why does `_asdict` exist when there is also the `.__dict__()` (i.e. the vars method)?

Comment: @wim: a named tuple uses slots, there is *no `__dict__` attribute*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is exactly what I was looking for, I will end up using what was in your answer however as it seems better than what I asked for.

Comment: Is there any difference between getting the OrderedDict out of a named tuple using `._asdict()` and using `vars`?  Where can I read about slots and how a namedtuple appears to have a `__dict__` attribute whilst you say it doesn't?

Comment: @wim: See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots; namedtuple-derived **classes** have a `__dict__` but **instances** of such classes do not.

Comment: @wim: as for `vars()`: `__dict__` on the `namedtuple` class is actually a property returning `self._asdict()`, see the [sample 'verbose' output](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: @wim: for `namedtuple` classes, the single-underscore names are explicitly documented; you can use them directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried it myself (on python 3.3.2+) and it was the opposite of how you explain.  `__dict__` constructed the `OrderedDict` , and `_asdict` simply did `return self.__dict__` with a note in the docstring saying: `"This method is obsolete.  Use vars(nt) or nt.__dict__ instead."`

Comment: @wim: Yes, I am actually now surprised that in Python 2.7 there is no `__dict__` attribute as the documentation clearly indicates there should be one. In Python 3 this is certainly the case. That said, **normally** classes with a `__slots__` produce instances without a `__dict__` and `namedtuple`-produced classes (in Python 3 at least) use an explicit `property` to give such instances a `__dict__` anyway. See the documentation I linked you to before.

Comment: @wim: I can see how the devs now state that `vars()` is the easier method to use in this case; I was going by the 2.7 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`namedtuples`can be indexed, so you don't need to turn one into a `dict` or use `vars()` to do what you want:

```
MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct","Var1 Var2 Var3")
instance = MyStruct(1, 2, 3)

fields_to_print = {'Var1', 'Var2'}
print(', '.join('{}: {}'.format(field, instance[i])
        for i, field in enumerate(instance._fields)
            if field in fields_to_print))
```

Output:

```
Var1: 1, Var2: 2
```