# django: use namedtuple instead of dict for **kwargs?

Tags: python, django, iterable-unpacking

why would this succeed

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(pk=1)
kwargs = {'name': 'me',
           'age_desc': 'getting older'
}
qs.update(**kwargs)
```

but not this?

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(pk=1)
nt =  collections.namedtuple('nt','name, age_desc')
kwargs = nt('me', 'getting older') 
qs.update(**kwargs)
```

Is there no way to use `namedtuples` instead of dicts when it come to unpacking parameters in `django`?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think Python keyword argument unpacking (the `**` syntax) supports named tuples, but you can use the `_asdict()` method of named tuple objects to get a dictionary from a named tuple. Or `vars()` on 3.x, and possibly on 2.7.5 ([Get the object name of a specific object from namedtuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840457/get-the-object-name-of-a-specific-object-from-namedtuple/19840533#19840533) has some discussion of the state of 2.7.5 installations).